# Implementing IOrganizationService

Tags: wcf, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been working on implementing the IOrganizationService interface in the CRM 2011 SDK - At first I wrote a simple Windows Service wrapper and this was throwing serialization exceptions any time i tried connecting to it. So I wrote a simple host for IIS. At first it seemed to work but any time there is a Fault in the service it throws the same error when trying to connect to the service after the first attempt.

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error whi
trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. The InnerException
message was 'Error in line 1 position 497. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request
contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts:WhoAmIRequest'. The
deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the
ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'WhoAmIRequest' and namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts'.'.
```

I am at a bit of a loss here - it works fine - throws a fault somwhere - attempt to reconnect and throws this error. After which I must re-compile and deploy the DLL to the IIS site bin dir again. I can provide some small code samples of if needed but keep in mind that I am inheriting the interface directly from the SDK assembly.

EDIT:
And I am unable to change the program the connects to the WCF Service as it is a third-party tool. When using the traditional web-services it is fine.

EDIT (Implementation Code - Excluding the implemented methods ..>):

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
         MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue,
        Name = "OrganizationServiceImplementation",
        Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts")]
    public class OrganizationServiceImplementation : IOrganizationService
    {
    }
```

Comment: post your code, and using IOrganizationService is quite straightforward, just look at msdn examples

Comment: I've been looking at MSDN for a little while now and I have not seen anything stating how to implement the CRM IOrganizationService - do you have a link?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: No problem - I am attempting to implement a different variant of the /XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc endpoint. My goal here is to use the CRM 2011 SDK to connect to this alternate endpoint. This works great until the service throws an FaultException. Once this has happened - the client application throws the serialization exception.

Comment: I'm going to guess that very few people have ever implemented their own version because they haven't needed to.  Why are you creating a different variant of the Organization.svc?

Comment: I need to apply some data transformations to records as they are created. The third-party tool imports data into the system - and there are a number of fields that need to be modified before they go into the system. Unfortunately a plug-in will not suffice.

Comment: Which third-party tool is it ? "Big" ones (Scribe, just to name one) should allow you to implement any data transformation you want... Also: If you're on premise, there is *nothing* limiting the power of plugins, as long as you register them outside the sandbox (Isolation: None). Re-implementing the Organization Service to apply some PreCreate transforms sounds a bit overkill

Comment: Agree with Alex - what transformations do you need to do that you can't do via plugin?  There aren't many limitations to what you can do in a plugin, at least in terms of data transformation.